# Uncaught TypeError in HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, css, html, forms

I'm trying to replicate a form builder similar to http://bootsnipp.com/j87klPolka/formbuilder3.html.

I'm fairly new to HTML/CSS/JS so I'm not sure if I'm doing this right. I'm just trying to do the frontend of this, so storing the data for the form being created isn't an issue right now. Thanks! Below is the code:

```
 <html>
<head>
    <title>Form Builder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Sign_in.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/landing-page.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<style>
#div1 {width:50%; height:50%; padding:50px; border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}

</style>    
<script>
    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>

    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend>Hello</legend>

<ul id="drag-elements">
    <li draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group" >
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Text</label>  
        <div class="col-md-4" >
        <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="form-control input-md">
        </div>
    </div>
    </li>

    <li draggable="true"  ondragstart="drag(event)">
    <!-- Password input-->
    <div class="form-group" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="passwordinput">Password Input</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="passwordinput" name="passwordinput" type="password" placeholder="placeholder" class="form-control input-md">
        <span class="help-block">help</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    </fieldset>
    </form>

    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: _Uncaught TypeError in HTML/CSS_ where is the error?

Comment: @Michael It's at the appendChild method.
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: Consider using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/). You may find it easier than just DOM alone in your scripts...

Comment: @Mirabilis I've read the jQuery is easier, however, if i were to implement this with just DOM, how would i go about fixing this error?

Comment: @Mirabilis Careful... "use jQuery" is [almost never](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48195) a good answer.

Comment: @Mirabilis not good to recommend jQuery as an answer until they know the technicalities of the DOM behind it.

Comment: Your `<div>` with ID `div1` is not closed. Could be a problem

Comment: @phi I closed it and it still comes with the same error.

Comment: Should be titled: "Uncaught TypeError in *JavaScript*"

Comment: @AaronGillion, that is why I offered it as a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<li>`s are draggable, but they have no `id` set, which you are trying to access in your `drag` method. Simply set an `id` to each of the draggable list items to make it work.

https://jsfiddle.net/Hatchet/3y3xyg0b/

Comment: @ktran15 Hm... Try dynamically generating another draggable element after the first one is placed. But, that is another question. :) For now, if my answer has solved your problem, you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both me and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Happy Coding!